# No result if search contains dot and wildcard

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I use azure search and have some document with a field like this {"Nr": "123.334.93"}.

If i search for querytype=full&search=123.334.93 then it found multiple document and if I search for querytype=full&search="123.334.93" then it found one document. This is as expected.

But if I search for querytype=full&search=123.334.9* I expect multiple document starting with 123.334.9 but none result are given back.

Do I miss somthing?

The same is when I use a regex expression like this querytype=full&search=/123\.334\.9.*/

Comment: Hi. Are you setting an analyzer on your field? If you are using the standard analyzer, I'd expect the first query 123.334.93 and second query "123.334.93" to return the same results. Your query with the suffix operator * should return all documents that match the 123.334.9 prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Comment from Yahnoosh.

The analyzer of the field was set to "de.microsoft". I change that to "standard.lucene", recreate and fill the index and it works as expected.

It seems that I have to be more carefully to set the analyzer and only use specific ones for fields with language specific content.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks correct to me and should work.

A couple of things you might look into.

1) Sometimes you need to escape the `*` like this:

```
querytype=full&search=123.334.9\*
```

Usually, this is only necessary if you have more search terms after the `*`.

2) You can also narrow the fields searched down to only the field you need (for better efficiency) like this:

```
querytype=full&search=Nr:123.334.9\*
```

Hope this helps.